# Display a dynamically content growing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, handlebars.js

Assume, I have a user page where user can select a subject to learn and a button to upload questions as well.

[Basic View Of a Subject Page](http://jsfiddle.net/6vrwc3y4/1/) - User selects a subject and got a  view like in the fiddle

```
<div class="dataContainer">
 <div class="clsContextContainer">
    <a href="intro.php">Chapter1</a>
    <a href="basic.php">Chapter2</a>
    <a href="next.php">Chapter3</a>
    <a href="advanced.php">Chapter4</a>
    <a href="future.php">Chapter5</a>
 </div>
 <div class="clsContentContainer">
   <div class="q"> Q: Question goes here
    <div class="c">C: a) choice1 b) choice2</div>
    <div class="a">AnswerButton</div></div>

   <div class="q"> Q: Question goes here
    <div class="c">C: a) choice1 b) choice2</div>
   <div class="a"> AnswerButton</div>
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have shown a simple page of what I want. My doubt is how to design this page so additional question will be automatically added.

**Solution1**

User uploads single question or a file which contains list of questions. One of the administrator approves it[Not a duplicate question, valid one], Then it should be added to this subject page.

I can use `handlebars.js` and where I can maintain a template like I shown in the fiddle and a context page. Once one of the administrator approves, I can add new question(s) to the list of available contexts.[`MODIFYING A FILE IN THE SERVER`] So when user renders the page next time, new question will also be added.

**My Doubt** - Is it safe to modify a file in the serer through script?

**Solution2**:

I can maintain a table in the server `questionsSubName`. User adds new question(s).Admin approves it. So add that question to the table in the server.

While rendering, read questions from the db, then render it.

**My doubt**: I don't feel its a feasible one, since querying db often is not the best way for this kinda situation.

**Solution3**

I can have lists of files as shown in the fiddle [`anchor tag`]. User adds a new question. Admin approves it.

(i)Manually creates/modifies the files which corresponds to chapters. `create` - I want to limit 50questions per chapter. If one chapter reaches 50 questions, I need to create another. So create comes into the picture here. If a chapter has less than 50 questions, modify it.

ii) Do it through script.

But I am not sure whether I am doing it in the right way. Please suggest me what way I can do or Is there any other framework which can help me in this situation.

**EDIT**

After reading comments, `handlebars js with tables` is the best solution.

```
    <div class="q"> {{{Question}}}
    <div class="c">{{{Choices}}}
    <div class="a">AnswerButton</div>
```

This could be my template page.

Context page will be like

```
   {
     Questions:[
        {Q: questionString, C: ChoiceString},
        next one
     ]
   }
```

I have to read set of questions from the server, for eg: I have 5 chapters for a subject and 220 questions in the table.

Table format:

```
 Question Id Column

 Question Column

 Choice Column

 Answer Column
```

So If user clicks `chapter1`, I will read first 50 questions from the table and make a context, then render it. If user clicks `chapter5`, read last 50 questions and rmake a context, then render it.

Is it feasible?

Comment: Go with option 2. Likely a simple query like this is not going to be what bottlenecks your application. Also, MySQL (if not all modern RDBMS) cache queries, so if 100 visitors all view the same page a few seconds apart, your DB server should cache those queries so anything after the first query will be almost instant.

Comment: From the scenario you explained here, I think using database table `Solution2` to maintain questions would be a good solution to this. This is beneficial because the repetition of same questions can be avoided easily at the time adding the question itself. Also the future enhancement like upvotes/ downvotes to questions, marking question as favorite will also be easy to implement and manipulate.

Comment: Using PHP to modify the HTML files directly could work, especially if the modifications are done very infrequently, but it is *very* easy to mess something up. One little mistake and the new HTML could be completely malformed or even worse, it could wipe the whole file. Also, you may decide months down the road that, oh, you should have used a `<div>` instead of a `<p>`. Then what do you do? You have all these static files you need to manually sort through whereas with a database this would all be trivial.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Suyog. Please see my edits

Comment: To answer your edit, I would go with two tables. One for questions, one for choices. I'm not sure what you mean by `Answer Column` though.

Comment: @Mike, User can select an answer and click `check` button to check the answer. So one of four choices is the right answer. So Answer column will have that choice.

Comment: I would include that in the Choices table then. Just add a column something like `is_correct INT(1)` and set that to 1 if it's the correct answer, otherwise 0.